# MS SQL Server query result to XML SOAP envelope

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, soap

I need to get a XML SOAP envelope as result of a MS SQL Server query, like this one:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:usercontrol">
  <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:Action>
      <urn:CDUSER>2</urn:CDUSER>
      <urn:IDUSER>jd</urn:IDUSER>
      <urn:NMUSER>John Doe</urn:NMUSER>
      <urn:DTINSERT>2019-09-12</urn:DTINSERT>
    </urn:Action>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My query:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:usercontrol' AS urn, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv)
SELECT
    '' AS [soapenv:Header], 
(
SELECT
    CDUSER AS [urn:CDUSER],
    IDUSER AS [urn:CDUSER],
    NMUSER AS [urn:CDUSER],
    CONVERT(varchar, DTINSERT, 120) AS [urn:DTINSERT]
FROM
    ADUSER
WHERE
    CDUSER = 2
FOR XML PATH('urn:newAction')
) AS [soapenv:Body]
FOR XML PATH('soapenv:Envelope')
```

Well, the result is not far away, but not what I want:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:usercontrol">
  <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>&lt;urn:newAction xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:usercontrol"&gt;&lt;urn:CDUSER&gt;2jdJohn Doe&lt;/urn:CDUSER&gt;&lt;urn:DTINSERT&gt;2019-09-12 11:09:45&lt;/urn:DTINSERT&gt;&lt;/urn:newAction&gt;</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can you help me?
Many thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution. It is using XQuery and its FLWOR expression.

It is better to use this approach for a couple of reasons:

- To prevent namespaces mushrooming in the output XML.
- Very easy to shape overall XML output structure.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (CDUSER INT, IDUSER VARCHAR(10), NMUSER VARCHAR(20), DTINSERT DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl (CDUSER, IDUSER, NMUSER, DTINSERT) VALUES
(2, 'jd', 'John Doe', GETDATE());
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:usercontrol' AS urn,
                    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv)
SELECT (
SELECT CDUSER AS [urn:CDUSER],
    IDUSER AS [urn:IDUSER],
    NMUSER AS [urn:NMUSER],
    FORMAT(DTINSERT, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [urn:DTINSERT]
FROM @tbl
WHERE CDUSER = 2
FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:usercontrol">
    <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:Action>
        {
            for $x in /root/r
            return $x/*
        }
        </urn:Action>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>');
```

**Output**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:usercontrol">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:Action>
      <urn:CDUSER>2</urn:CDUSER>
      <urn:IDUSER>jd</urn:IDUSER>
      <urn:NMUSER>John Doe</urn:NMUSER>
      <urn:DTINSERT>2021-02-05</urn:DTINSERT>
    </urn:Action>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'm so grateful to to you, Yitzhak. Your solution is working fine.

Comment: @CarlosdeSá, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

When writing nested XML statements, you need to ensure your inner queries use the `TYPE` operator. Otherwise you end up with what you have. This is untested, but it should therefore simply be this

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:usercontrol' AS urn,
                    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv)
SELECT '' AS [soapenv:Header],
       (SELECT CDUSER AS [urn:CDUSER],
               IDUSER AS [urn:CDUSER],
               NMUSER AS [urn:CDUSER],
               CONVERT(varchar(20), DTINSERT, 120) AS [urn:DTINSERT]
        FROM ADUSER
        WHERE CDUSER = 2
       FOR XML PATH('urn:newAction'),TYPE) AS [soapenv:Body]
FOR XML PATH('soapenv:Envelope');
```

*Also, get in the habit of defining your length, precision and scales now, so that it doesn't bite you in the foot later.*

Comment: Thank you, very much, Larnu.

Comment: Thank you, very much, Larnu. Your solution works, but repeats the namespaces in the tag urn:newAction. The solution of Yitzhak, above, works fine.